# What RF frequency can I freely use without a government's permission legally?

Tags: rf, frequency, radio

- So I want to create a transmitter that sends digital signals that have 30 kilometres of range but in my country.
- Radio transmission without authorisation is only allowed upto 50 metres.
- I researched about ISM bands but I don't know if it's allowed to transmit on them for distances up to 5 kilometres.
- Please let me know if it's allowed or not, or if there is other internationally free to use limitless frequency that I can use.

Comment: For most transmission purposes a license is usually needed. You can get an amateur license in most countries for doing non-professional stuff after passing a simple test. For unlicensed transmissions you can look at for example, [this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/what-are-the-us-rules-about-unlicensed-low-power-transmissions?rq=1). I would recommend you to check out the ham-radio communities like [this one](https://ham.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoeyMallone Can i use 2.4GHz frequency?

Comment: 2.4GHz - Hmm, you want to transmit Wifi? I think, I saw someone do that actually on youtube. And they were doing it in Canada. [No promotion intended](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYJFwXw1ZIc).

But as far as I know, outside the [amateur radio bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_frequency_allocations), you cannot do that.

Comment: @JoeyMallone let's say, audio in PWM form?

Comment: @JoeyMallone because i read that it's reserved globally

Comment: Yes, 2.4GHz is outside the bands where you can transmit as a hobbyist or amateur. I don't think you can do that legally.

Comment: @JoeyMallone But can i transmit it high power that it could reach 30 kilometres?

Comment: Apart from the legal question, if you are just asking about the physics and engineering of doing something like this, then I would say, maybe. But it still looks difficult. People have been transmit 2.4GHz wifi signals for a distance of upto 12km. I am not sure about *"audio in PWM form"*. I am not even sure what you mean by *"audio in PWM form"*. Maybe I lack the required expertise and someone else might jump in to answer your question.

Comment: @JoeyMallone because i fear i could jam a few wifi signals

Comment: That's exactly why you need to contact your local licensing authority. The em spectrum is strictly controlled and policed.

Comment: @Chu I mean, i'm a teen and don't have a citizen card

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this one](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/broadcasting-a-wifi-ssid-long-distance?noredirect=1&lq=1). Maybe it helps. As far as being a teen is concerned, there is no age limit to getting a "HAM License" for transmitting on HAM Bands. Transmitting on 2.4GHz might be a different story.

Comment: That's exactly why ...

Comment: At extremely slow datarates and with huge antennas, you can transmit very long distances with low power. The "huge antennas" mean low frequencies. Pehaps install those antennas up in mountains, for even better range.

Comment: @Joey Mallone By the way, 2.4 GHz is also an amateur band in many regions, and its use if often allowed even to the lowest license classes.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, ah ok. That is new information for me. Thank you.

Comment: Lower frequency would be better for the distance. Look into 443, or 900 MHz bands and LORA chips.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @Pangus Indonesia

Comment: Find out your country's regulations (maybe online), and they will tell you what the rules are for transmitting. You need the government's permission to use any frequency. You might *already have* permission for some frequencies or types of signals (e.g. wi-fi).